# Difference between vector of integer type and long long integer type

Tags: vector, stl

What is the difference between `vector<int>A` and `vector<long long>A` ? which one can store maximum number of integer values?

Answer (score 0):

This memory​ is dynamically allocated so theoretically you can have as many elements as you like. The real limits are imposed by the hardware capacity. On the same hardware though, the vector of `int` will store more values than the vector of `long long` simply because an `int` is smaller than an `long long`.

Comment: Could you please explain it in details? i can't understand yet !

Comment: Ok, so the vector  is a data structure which allocates chunks of memory on the fly (I.e. it grows dinamically). So the real limit is the amount of RAM the machine has. But if you take a limited amount of RAM, say 1 MB, of course you can allocate more ints than long longs in that limited amount of memory.

Comment: It's better if you ask more specific what you did not understand. Otherwise, it can be a rather lengthy discussion.

Comment: How it related with the RAM?

Comment: It actually depends on the operating system. Every memory allocation must correspond to some physical (hardware) memory place. Most of the time it is the Random access memory, but it can be also flash(hard-drive) and the like. The point is that when your 'vector' allocates some memory, it means that some physical zone in hardware will be occupied: let's say when you have a vector of 100 integers this usually means that some 100 * 4 bytes of memory will be occupied. That must be physical memory in the end and like I said, it is most of the times the RAM.

Comment: thanks and grateful to you . i understand this better than before !

Comment: Good, if anything else needs clarifications  drop a comment